# Why Numba is not working with time in this code?

Tags: python-3.x, time, numba

I am trying following code with python3:

```
import time
duration = 5

from numba import njit
@njit 
def myfn(): 
    num = 3
    starttime = time.time()
    while True: 
        print("Checking", num)
        endtime = time.time()
        if (endtime - starttime) > duration: 
            print("Time up.")
            return
        num += 2

myfn()
```

However, it is giving following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/abcde/testing_numba", line 20, in <module>
    myfn()
  File "/home/abcde/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 414, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "/home/abcde/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 357, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
Unknown attribute 'time' of type Module(<module 'time' (built-in)>)

File "testing_numba", line 11:
def myfn(): 
    <source elided>
        num = 3
        starttime = time.time()
 ^

During: typing of get attribute at /home/abcde/testing_numba (11)

File "testing_numba", line 11:
def myfn(): 
    <source elided>
        num = 3
        starttime = time.time()
 ^
```

Especially note `Unknown attribute 'time' of type Module(<module 'time' (built-in)>)`

Without numba, the code works fine.

How can this error be corrected?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a nutshell: As the error message suggests, Numba doesn't support this python-feature (list of [supported python-features](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#supported-python-features)).

Normally, one would reconsider using such python-objects in nopython-numba-functions, because there is nothing to be gained speed-wise from such objects.

Alternatives are:

- using python-mode, i.e. `nb.jit(forceobj=True)`. The function will "work" in this case, but the speed-up gains due to the 3. point from the explanation bellow will be missing.
- using [`np.objmode`-content manager](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/user/withobjmode.html#the-objmode-context-manager) to turn on the python-mode only for special lines of the function.

---

Numba's speed up in nopython-mode comes from

1. no need for python-interpreter: the code is compiled to python-bytecode which must run in python-vm, but to assembler which can be executed directly by the cpu.
2. no need for dynamic dispatch: the types of variables are deduced/known at compile time, thus the meaning of operations like `a+b` must not be resolved at run time (dynamic dispatch) it is backed-in into the assembler already (static dispatch)
3. no longer python objects are used (e.g. `int`- or `float`- or `list`-objects) but "corresponding" types in plain C like 64bit-ints or doubles.

While getting rid of 1. and 2. might get us about 2-3 times faster code (but there could be no gains at all, depending on how much overhead 1. and 2. produce), the holy grail of speeding up is the 3. point: using it has the potential of being about 100 times faster then pure python! [This SO-post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46723823/5769463) is an analysis of the speed-up potential for above points (but done for cython) with more details.

Obviously, in order to use C types for python objects, numba must know the correspondence between Python-object and C types.

This can be easily done for numpy-arrays like `np.zeros(n, dtype=np.int32)`: it more or less corresponds to a pointer of type `int32_t*` with additional meta-information (like the length of the array).

It is possible to convert some python constructs to C types during the run time, like lists consisting only of int-objects (which are not too big), e.g.:

```
@nb.njit
def fun(a):
    print(a)

fun([1,2]) # works
fun([1,2,2**65]) # doesn't work, because 2**65 cannot be represented with uint64
```

But this obviously produces overhead during the run time and should be avoided, if possible. Instead [`typed lists`](https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/dev/reference/pysupported.html#typed-list) should be used, which from memory layout are very similar to 1d-numpy-arrays.

For such a complex python-object like the `time`-module, there is no corresponding C type (which would provided meaningful speed-up), and thus it is not supported by numba in nopython-mode.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, `numba` does not support the `time` module and it cannot be used in `nopython` mode. It will work with `@jit` instead of `@njit`, but the performance gain won't be as good.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62424842/7114716) for a potential solution and more details.